# While не работает с несколькими условиями Питон

Tags: python

kk = 1, но вайл не прекращается, если добавлено 2 условие. Правильно ли я записал?

```
        while (kk != 1) or (i != 10):
            try:
                time.sleep(1)
                InfoIP[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
                InfoIP2[0] = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="d_clip_button"]/span').text
            except Exception:
                i += 1
            else:
                kk = 1
```

Comment: В каких случаях вам нужно остановить цикл?

Comment: когда трай успешно завершился, или когда количество неуспешных попыток достигло 10

Comment: замените or на and